# Maintaining state in Vaadin on browser back button

Tags: vaadin, browser-history, vaadin7

Vaadin loses the content on pressing the browser back button. If I have populated a table and if I go back to that page, the page is empty again. How can I save state of pages so that when I go back to them using browser back button they're in the state I left them.

I am using Navigator currently.

I am basically uploading an excel sheet using Upload component, and populating my table on the same page using table.additem(). I have a functionality that when user clicks on a row of the table, user navigates to the next page, but when I press the browser back button then the table is gone, and the upload shows no document selected.

The navigation updates Application/#!Main/ the variable part changes.

I just want my application to retain the state as it would do with a refresh.

Comment: are you using Navigator/View:s?

Comment: Yes. I am using Navigator & Views

Comment: can you provide some minimal code to show the problem.  or could you at least be more verbose, how you fill the table (e.g. ctor, enter(), ...), if you use a container, etc.  and we are talking about browser history navigation _within_ the app just into other views (e.g. only the `#!...` parts changes)?

Comment: Please see the updated description.

Comment: Are "table" and "next page" their own Vaadin Views registered to the Vaadin Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. You should add scope @UIScope to your views, in this scope session works, and state will be saved.